# How to make a drop down menu in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, menu

My idea is that, in order to provide to the user different options to choose it would be very interesting to include some type of IBOutlet with a drop down menu on it.

This is how it should be seen. 
How is the best way to do this?
[image: Drop down menu] Any suggestion would be very appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/PhamBaTho/BTNavigationDropdownMenu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that the down arrow is a button to trigger the drop-down that you've illustrated, the first suggestion that comes to mind is to create an IBAction for that button that presents a table view as a child view controller. This table view will list out the "different options".

Comment: Thanks bro!!!! I have presented a small table view as you have already suggested to me.

Comment: No problem. There are many ways to do this, but that's the first that came to mind. Also it's good because it separates your TableView code (delegate & datasource etc) from your "parent" view controller.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a UIAlertController. Apple suggests that developers follow the same consistent design throughout the entire OS. As a plus, UIAlertController is pretty easy to use. (Beware though, UIAlertView is deprecated. Don't use it by mistake.)

You could also (if you have a lot of choices) use a [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/index.html).

Comment: Thanks man for your help. It was very appreciated